# AWS Cognito User Pool Sign up issue using email id

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have created a userpool in AWS Cognito and has enabled below properties.

1. Enabled MFA (Required). SMS text message has the 2nd factor.(Which second factors do you want to enable?)
2. Enabled user signup on there own.
3. Use Email or Phone number to sign up.
4. Which attributes do you want to verify? I have configured  Email or Phone number.

   I have used Android SDK and implemented sign up and sign in functionality.

Scenarios:

1. If I use phone number, the phone number is verified and it works fine.
2. If I use email, I get a link to email and its verified but sign up is not successful and it expects a code.

So my doubt is if I use email id in scenario 2 to sign up:

1. Should I also need to use phone number to sign up, since it is required for sending SMS text message for the verification. If user doesn't wish to provide phone number how can I handle this?
2. Should I need to make MFA optional.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making MFA "optional" from "required", the issue was resolved.